# Batch answer to getting underlying columns in SQL Server 2012 views and queries

Tags: sql-server-2012, schema

I have a database in SQL Server 2012 that I need to document. It has about 80 tables and in excess of 800 views and queries. What I need to do is find out the column dependencies of each column in each view or query, and if possible also note any constants used in each column definition.

I know I can use dependency trees to get all the related views and tables themselves, but does anyone have a good idea about how to extract the individual definition of each column and its alias if present?

For example, I have a view called `vwRepoRisk` which takes an assortment of columns from an underlying table `tblRepos` and another view `vwRiskValues` (itself based on another view and table). Most of the columns are returned by simple selects, but several are calculated using two or more of the underlying data columns.

I need to be able to show the derivation of each column in `vwRepoRisk` with reference to the underlying table and view. And it needs to be recursive!

I have a horrible feeling that this is going to involve regex somewhere :(